# What does contract.filters return in ethers.js?

Tags: events, ethereum, ethers.js

I came across ethers.js library's event filters function `contract.filters`. See below codes from ethers.js documentation.

https://docs.ethers.org/v5/concepts/events/

```
abi = [
  "event Transfer(address indexed src, address indexed dst, uint val)"
];

contract = new Contract(tokenAddress, abi, provider);

// List all token transfers *from* myAddress
contract.filters.Transfer(myAddress)
// {
//   address: '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F',
//   topics: [
//     '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
//     '0x0000000000000000000000008ba1f109551bd432803012645ac136ddd64dba72'
//   ]
// }
```

1. What is in the returned value inside `topics:[]`, what is each string value represent? Is each event represented in its transaction hash?
2. And also what is the sort order of each event? Would the latest event be the first in the topics array?

Thank you!

I also looked at solidity's documentation on events but still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is in the returned value inside `topics:[]`, what is each string value represent? Is each event represented in its transaction hash?

Since this event is non-anonymous (most events are; missing the `anonymous` keyword at the end of the event definition), `topics[0]` represents the event signature.

Event signature is a keccak256 hash of the event name and argument types.

In this case hash of string `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` (`uint` is an alias for `uint256` and the longer version is used for signatures).

Following `topics` items are the `indexed` params. Since there's 2 indexed params in your event, the total size of the array should be 3 (1 signature + 2 indexed params). I'm not sure why the 3rd item is missing from the code in your question.

> And also what is the sort order of each event? Would the latest event be the first in the topics array?

They are sorted by the order of their execution. So the following code returns `EventB`, then `EventA` and finally `EventB`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
  event EventA();
  event EventB();

  function foo() external {
    emit EventB();
    emit EventA();
    emit EventB();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Petr Hejda said

You can see information about topic here

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=topic#events
https://medium.com/mycrypto/understanding-event-logs-on-the-ethereum-blockchain-f4ae7ba50378

And use `keccak256` hash function like:
`ethers.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")`
to calculate the event topic you wish to filter.

https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-keccak256